# Datatype in progress 4gl

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Integer and decimal datatype accepts only 10 digits after that getting error message value too large to fit in integer or decimal.What is the maximum limit of integer and decimal datatype in progress 4gl?Is it possible to print 100 digits after decimal place in progress 4gl?

Comment: Please at least try to use the help files and manuals. Or ask a specific question as there are always ways of doing things

Comment: I would think one could still ask a simple/obvious question, and then, upon using help files and manuals, answer their own question. It seems there is some kind of need to display that many, but there is currently no way to do it using a single variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible to print 100 digits after the decimal in Progress. But honestly, why would you?

If you don't need to do that specific calculations you can always use a CHARACTER field.

From the F1-help:

**DECIMAL**

> DECIMAL data consists of decimal numbers up to 50 digits in length
>   including up to 10 digits to the right of the decimal point.

**INTEGER**

> An INTEGER consists of 32-bit data (whole numbers).

(Integer must be between -2147483648 and 2147483647).

**INT64**

> An INT64 consists of 64-bit data (whole numbers).

(INT64 must be between -9223372036854775808 and 9223372036854775807)

Note that these are absolute limits and has nothing to do with the display format of the variable/field/widget. Display format (FORMAT statement) only affects the possibility to display and can be even more limiting (but can also be overridden programmatically).